# Geom rect fill not working properly for dates

Tags: r, ggplot2

There is a problem with the `geom_rect` of ggplot2. I want to shade the area left of the vline with light blue. However, it is acting funny. (Maybe because the date column involved).

The code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

df <- read.csv("~/Desktop/dataset.csv")

# df <- df[!duplicated(df$caseid),]

df$createdat <- as.numeric(as.character(df$createdat))
df$resolutionat <- as.numeric(as.character(df$resolutionat))



df <- df[df$resolutionat != 0,]

df <- mutate(df, age = (resolutionat - createdat))
df <- mutate(df, counts = assigneechangecount + teamchangecount)
df <- mutate(df, isbreached = rbinom(388, 1, 0.2))
df<- mutate(df, resolutiondate = as.POSIXct(df$resolutionat, origin="1970-01-01"))

xstart <- as.POSIXct("2016-04-26 20:36:21 IST")
xend <- as.POSIXct("2016-04-28 12:00:38 IST")


print(ggplot(df, aes(resolutiondate, age, size = counts, color = factor(isbreached))) +
             geom_point(alpha = 0.4) +
             geom_point(shape = 21) +
             scale_y_continuous(labels = comma) +
             geom_vline(data=df, aes(xintercept = as.numeric(resolutiondate[300]), color = "blue")) +
             geom_rect(data = df, aes(xmin=xstart, xmax=xend, ymin=-Inf, ymax=Inf), fill = "light blue", alpha = 0.2) 
             )
```

The resulting plot:

[image]

The data is as follows:

```
> head(df)
   caseid  createdat resolutionat assigneechangecount teamchangecount  age
1 2143843 1462892601   1462894326                   1               1 1725
2 2143840 1462892071   1462893544                   1               1 1473
3 2143839 1462892018   1462892466                   1               1  448
4 2143838 1462891887   1462893433                   1               1 1546
5 2143830 1462890910   1462893543                   1               1 2633
6 2143829 1462890812   1462892469                   1               1 1657
  counts isbreached      resolutiondate
1      2          0 2016-05-10 21:02:06
2      2          1 2016-05-10 20:49:04
3      2          0 2016-05-10 20:31:06
4      2          0 2016-05-10 20:47:13
5      2          1 2016-05-10 20:49:03
6      2          0 2016-05-10 20:31:09
```

**I wanted to plot the area to the left of vline a light blue**

Comment: @bouncyball That returns this error: `Error: Invalid input: time_trans works with objects of class POSIXct only` (setting `xmin` to -Inf)  :(

Comment: df <- read.csv("~/Desktop/dataset.csv") is not very helpful. You'll need to add some data to the question.

Comment: @dww Added a chunk of the dataset.

Comment: @beetroot Added the pastebin link of the data

Comment: If you want the rectangle to the left of the line, don't you need to make`xmax` the same date as your line?  The date I get for `df$resolutiondate[300]` is in between your`xstart` and `xend` dates.

Comment: @beetroot That's just a silly request; we don't need all the data to work on this. Perhaps a subset that covered the extremes of the x-axis is all we need. We more than likely don't even need the info for the scales. In essence, the issue is about placing a `geom_rect()` at some extreme end of the data.

Comment: Thank you @GavinSimpson. Just did the rollback!

Comment: @beetroot given the plot *shows all the data* (I tried it), asking for all the data to reproduce the plot is asking for all the data and *is* silly and pointless. The problem isn't anything related to the data at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `geom_rect()` call probably wants to be:

```
geom_rect(aes(xmin = xstart, xmax = xend, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf),
          fill = "light blue", alpha = 0.2, colour = NA)
```

because

- you don't need to respecify the `data` arg, and
- you don't want that red/green border.

There's always a little bit of padding on plots, so make sure you have an xstart that is well beyond the limits of the data shown on the plot

```
xstart <- as.POSIXct("2016-04-23 20:36:21 IST")
```

Then all you need to do is to set the x axis limits to the limits of the data:

```
lims <- with(df, range(resolutiondate))
```

Next we need to use this. If you use `xlim()` to set the x-axis limits then anything outside these limits, i.e. the start of your rectangle geom, will get thrown out. What you want to use is `coord_cartesian()`, which takes limits as `Date` objects just fine:

```
## Clean up your plot
p <- ggplot(df, aes(resolutiondate, age, size = counts, color = factor(isbreached))) +
            geom_point(alpha = 0.4) +
            geom_point(shape = 21) +
            scale_y_continuous(labels = comma) +
            geom_vline(data=df, aes(xintercept = as.numeric(resolutiondate[300])),
                       color = "blue")
```

Now set appropropriate start and ends

```
xstart <- as.POSIXct("2016-04-23 20:36:21 IST")
xend <- with(df, resolutiondate[300])
```

Notice that you need `xend` to be `resolutiondate[300]` if you want to draw to the left of an up to this point.

Now add the `geom_rect()` layer and set the x-limits

```
p + geom_rect(aes(xmin = xstart, xmax = xend, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf),
              fill = "light blue", alpha = 0.2, colour = NA) +
    coord_cartesian(xlim = lims)
```

With that I get:

[image]

The key line is the `coord_cartesian()` part. You can think of this as like clipping the resulting image to those limits, whereas `xlim()` is more like clipping the data to those limits and then draws what's left.

Comment: You probably want an explicit `data = NULL` so that you don't get one rectangle for each row in the original dataset (which is why it doesn't look like `alpha = 0.2` currently)